# Parsing a blogspot XML file with Nokogiri

Tags: xml, xpath, nokogiri, blogspot

I have a blogspot exported xml file and it looks something like this:

```
<feed>
<entry>
<title> title </title>
<content type="html"> Content </content>
</entry>
<entry>
<title> title </title>
<content type="html"> Content </content>
</entry>
</feed>
```

How do I parse  with Nokogiri and Xpath???

Here is what I have :

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'


 doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("blogspot.xml"))

 doc.xpath('//content[@type="html"]').each do |node|
  puts node.text
 end
```

but it's not giving me anything :/

any suggestions? :/

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me. There were some problems with certain version of Nokigiri.

I get:

```
 Content
 Content
```

I'm using nokogiri (1.4.1 x86-mswin32)

Comment: thanks nigel - it turned out that i needed to be very very specific with my xpath expressions - or cull away at un needed attributes :D

Answer (score 0):

turns out that i had to delete the attributes for feed

```
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/' xmlns:georss='http://www.georss.org/georss' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' xmlns:thr='http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled on this question. The issue appears to be XML namespaces:

> "turns out that i had to delete the attributes for feed"

```
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/' xmlns:georss='http://www.georss.org/georss' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' xmlns:thr='http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0'>
```

XML Namespaces complicate accessing nodes because they provide a way to separate similar tags. Read the "Namespaces" section of [`Searching an HTML / XML Document`](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html).

Nokogiri also has the [`remove_namespaces!`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Document.html#method-i-remove_namespaces%21) method which is a sometimes-useful way of dealing with the problem but has some downsides too.